# Use Actionbarsherlock and viewpageindicator in the same activity.

Tags: android

I am trying  to use both Actionbarsherlock and viewpageindicator in the same activity but both of these need that you have extended the activity with different things. How can I solve this, for what I can understand you can't extend with two things. 
Thanks!

Comment: I mean, can i use both of these in the same activity? If not how do i do?